# Palavras chaves com Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Gostaria de fazer algo como:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pra cada  palavra que o usuário digita, ele ficasse assim como na imagem acima.

O mais próximo que consegui chegar foi saber a quantidade de palavras que ele digitou, segue código abaixo:

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                        <input id="first_name" type="text" class="validate palavras-chaves">
                        <label for="first_name">Palavras Chaves</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
var palavrasChaves = $(".palavras-chaves");
palavrasChaves.on("input",function(){
        var conteudo = palavrasChaves.val();
        var qntdPalavras = conteudo.split(/\S+/).length -1;
        console.log(qntdPalavras);
 
    });
    
    </script>
```

Comment: Como você está utilizando JQuery, existem [vários plugins](https://plugins.jquery.com/tag/tags/) com essa funcionalidade. Você quer algo pronto ou implementar "do zero"?

Comment: @Renan Seria interessante implementar do zero, mas poderia poderia me dizer quais plugins?

Comment: @Amanda da uma olhada no link que o Renan passou, tem varias opcoes boas

Comment: Tentei utilizar o TaggingJS e até funcionou no browser, mas o ideal seria ele separar por espaço, pois no celular só aplica a formatação quando saio do input. Será que teria como alterar?

Answer (score 1):

Se estiver utilizando jQuery, um que já utilizei e é bem fácil de se usar é o [bootstrap tags input](https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/).

> **OBS:** ele funciona apenas até o Bootstrap versão **3.3.7**

```js
$("input").tagsinput('items')
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" value="teste" data-role="tagsinput" />
```

Comment: como ficaria no celular? o ideal seria cada vez que ele clicasse espaço...

Comment: Eu entrei no site que é este link que coloquei na reposta, e quando digito no input fica uma seta no teclado, tipo como se fosse um **enter**, aí ele insere a `tag`.

Comment: Para usar o espaço use a opção com o código 32: `$("input").tagsinput({
   confirmKeys: [13, 32]
})`... o código 13 é do ENTER.

Comment: @Sam obrigado, realmente não mencionei que o plugin tem diversas opções de personalização também.

Answer (score 0):

Você está utilizando jQuery, poderia utilizar um plugin como o [TaggingJS](https://github.com/sniperwolf/taggingJS) e
com essa linha você resolveria seu problema. `$('#inputDaTag').tagging();`

Answer (score 0):

Eu utilizei esse e ficou bem legal:

https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

É só referenciar os arquivos js e css na página e deixar seu input assim:

```
 <input id="first_name" type="text" data-role="tagsinput" class="form-control">
```